# Facebook test accounts with pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-test-users

I'm creating a system which involves these steps:
1. Facebook user logs in with Facebook login (manage_pages scope)
2. One of user's Facebook page's access_token is being collected
3. Page's access token is then extended and stored in database for further use

The problem is, that I need to test it and when it comes to Facebook's "test-users", they just can't create a page. I created regular account for this purpose and added it as a Tester in Roles. But as I know it violates rules of Facebook and it's getting annoying as they trying to ban that account (and eventually will).
Any ideas?
Thanks!

P.s. sorry for any mistakes, not a native speaker.

Comment: How many more accounts besides your app admin/developer account do you need to test this? Testing with a multitude of accounts might make sense for certain features/functionality - but so far what you described doesn’t sound like such a case.

Comment: System I'm developing should be able to work with multiple pages of multiple users at the time. So I need to have more accounts, but I can't think of anything proper... And I don't see no questions on this topic anywhere, am I missing something?

Comment: Test users were able to create pages, when you log in as that user from the app dashboard. Have you verified that doesn’t work any more?

Comment: What do you mean by "when you log in as that user from the app dashboard"? I would just normally log in as that test user and if I try to create a page, everything seems ok until I type page's name/category and click Continue. I'm always getting "Error notice
There was a technical issue and your information wasn't submitted. Please reload the page and try again." :(

Comment: By the way, I found a topic on this issue... https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1379799389014320/

Comment: @rokastokas This topic is marked as solved, but many people have posted messages saying that this bug is back, and someone did open another issue, so now the last bug report regarding this issue is: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/983667641797373/

Comment: I was in similar situation, not able to create pages using test user. I think they fixed the issue recently. I am now able to create a page for a test user.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this same issue and was finally able to create a Test Page for a Test User. The basic instructions are found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages, but I will add how to actually create the Test Page using the Graph API Explorer.

1. Create a Test User.

   [image]
2. Click **Change permissions this test user granted to app** to ensure the `manage_pages` permission has been applied.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Get a User access token for the Test User.

   [image]
4. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Paste in the user Access Token you copied. Set the action to POST and enter the path like **/[TEST_USER_ID_HERE]/accounts** then enter fields corresponding to the following parameters (feel free to change the values):

   `{
       "name": "Test Page",
       "category_enum": "MEDIA",
       "about": "About test page",
       "picture": "[URL TO A PICTURE]",
       "cover_photo": {
           "url": "[URL TO A COVER PHOTO]"
       }
   }`

[image]

(note if you use the new beta version of the Graph Explorer, you can switch to JSON mode and just paste in the JSON directly)

Once that completes, it will return the new Test Page's ID. You can also call **/[TEST_USER_ID_HERE]/accounts** with the GET action to see that Page's ID again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a test page of category "Real Estate Agent". It seems that some categories require the City/State to be filled. I fixed it using the `category_enum=MEDIA` parameter.