# Facebook test user create page

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I am creating an app that uses facebook location information when a user creates a status update with a location (check in).  In order to do this with a test user I need to be able to create a fake page, but there seems to be a bug in facebook code where a test user cannot create a page.  The City/State field is always shown as invalid even when I enter valid information.  Is there any way to use test accounts to test status updates with location?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, cities and states are represented as pages, too - so test users can not access any real ones of those either.

Comment: So how can I create a page with an address as a test user?

Comment: Dunno if that’s possible. Perhaps easier to test with a real user that has a role in the app.

Comment: You may be able to create a page for the test user using the graph api explorer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586873/facebook-test-accounts-with-pages

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages